# Java HttpsURLConnection - Authorization with Spotify API

Tags: java, api, authorization, spotify

I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of days.
I'm attempting to authorize with Spotify using the Client Credentials authorization flow using Java. However, I keep getting the 411 Length Required HTTP error, despite having a Content-Length property.

```java
HttpsURLConnection spotifyAccounts = null;
            try {
                spotifyAccounts = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials").openConnection();
                spotifyAccounts.setDoOutput(true);
                spotifyAccounts.setDoInput(true);
                spotifyAccounts.setRequestMethod("POST");
                String unencodedAuthorizationKey = "Basic " + "42f48d16044a4c79b5168c5784889827" + ":" + "d6bb7a72e99342319e6b6d8c6fd3cedd";
                String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(unencodedAuthorizationKey.getBytes());
                spotifyAccounts.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedKey);
                spotifyAccounts.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                spotifyAccounts.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                int totalLength = 0;
                for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : spotifyAccounts.getRequestProperties().entrySet()) {
                    for(String string : entry.getValue()) {
                        totalLength += string.getBytes().length;
                    }
                }
                spotifyAccounts.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(totalLength));
                spotifyAccounts.connect();
            } catch(IOException ex) {}
```

Everytime I get the 411 error, I output the value of the Content-Length request property, like so:

```java
int code = 0;
            try {
                code = spotifyAccounts.getResponseCode();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(code != 200) {
                if(code == 411) {
                    System.out.println("Spotify Accounts - Content-Length: " + spotifyAccounts.getContentLength());
                    System.out.println("Spotify Accounts - Connecting User Agent: " + spotifyAccounts.getRequestProperty("User-Agent"));
                }
                // Other error code handling
            }
```

**Outputting the Content-Length always returns a value of 1564.**

I've tried many things, such as changing HttpsURLConnection to HttpURLConnection, changing the Content-Type header, and straight up setting Content-Length to 0. But all of these solutions still return the 411 Length Required error. Is there something else I'm missing, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spotify documentation says that you need to set `grant_type` in the body of the request, however `?grant_type=client_credentials` this does not work.
Instead, you can submit a body like this:

```
    byte[] input = "grant_type=client_credentials".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
        os.write(input);
    }
```